# Which `styled` import do I use? (MaterialUI)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

With the new `styled` API in MUI v5 there are a few different places a developer can import `styled` from, and they don't seem to be exactly the same. If anyone can help provide some clarity I'd greatly appreciate it!

The two places I know we can import `styled` from are:

- `@mui/material/styles`
- `@mui/system`

(Excluding `@mui/styles` as it sounds like it is being deprecated: https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#migrate-from-jss)

On https://mui.com/system/styled/ the examples reference `@mui/system`, however in the v4 Migration Guide it uses `@mui/material/styles`: https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#migrate-from-jss

Thanks!